# The number of integers for which $n-S_n=1234$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a positive integer $n$ , let $S_n$ denotes the sum of digits of $n$.The number of integers for which $n-S_n=1234$,equals

I really don't know what to do in this  .

I don't know  $\bmod$  thing .

Comment: Can you prove $n-S(n)$ is always a multiple of $9$ ?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling I think no .

Comment: Do you remember that a number is a multiple of $3$ if and only if the sum of its digits is a multiple of $3$? Well this is the version of that result meant for toddlers who already had the two practice wheels from their bikes taken off.

Answer (score 5):

Notice $n\equiv S_n\bmod 9$, therefore $n-S_n$ is a multiple of $9$, while $1234$ is not. So there are $0$ values and we are done.

Comment: I don't know what mod is

Comment: basically $n-s(n)$ is always a multiple of $9$. Because if $n=\overline{a_ka_{k-1}\dots a_1}$ then $n-s(n)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^k a_i(10^i-1)$ and every summand is a multiple of $9$.

Comment: +1, definitely the clever way to do it. One can bruteforce this problem by observing that sum of an $n$ digit number is at most $9n$, so clearly, any such $n$ must be $4$ digits and thus $1234 \leqslant n \leqslant 1234+36 = 1270$. However, then the sum of digits is bounded by $1+2+6+9 = 18$, so one only really needs to check $18$ numbers. But this is very slow, of course, and doesn't really use any mathematics...

Comment: If the original poster hasn't met mod yet, why do you think he knows $\Sigma$ and summand?

Comment: I don't know, some of my college classmates work with sums and don't know about modular arithmetic.

Comment: @AlexWertheim That is what I thought at first, and it is really fast to do in a computer for values of to $10^8$

Answer (score 5):

Here's an explanation without using mod. Suppose we have a number $ABCD$ such that $ABCD-(A+B+C+D)=1234$. Then:

$1000A+100B+10C+D-A-B-C-D=1234\\999A+99B+9C=1234\\9(111A+11B+C)=1234$

But $1234$ is not a multiple of $9$, so this is impossible. You can see that the same thing happens for any number of digits, so if we take any number and subtract its digit sum, the result is always a multiple of $9$.

Comment: How you get this step $$1000A+100B+10C+D-A-B-C-D$$

Comment: Are you aware the number $ABCD$ written in decimal is equal to $1000A+100B+10C+D $ ?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Thanks , Now I think I can prove it .

Answer (score 2):

Without using [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), and without even a divisibility argument, you can see that $S_n$ for $n$ somewhere in the region of $1234$ can't be more than $1+2+9+9=21 \implies$ not more than $1+2+4+9=16$. So there are only a few numbers to search.

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
n & S_n & \text{diff}\\ \hline
1234 & 10 & 1224\\
1235 & 11 & 1224\\
\cdots &  & \cdots\\
1239 & 15 & 1224\\
1240 & 7 & 1233\\
1241 & 8 & 1233\\
\cdots &  & \cdots\\
1249 & 16 & 1233\\
1250 & 8 & 1242\\
\end{array}$$

... and no values qualify.

Looking at the numbers directly doesn't always solve problems like this but sometimes it shows some interesting patterns that can start you in useful directions.